# If `v` is a class, can `v + 1 - 1` be optimized by compiler to `v`?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
struct S{
    int a, b;
    S() : a(0), b(10) {}
};

S operator + (const S& v, int n){
    S r = v;
    r.a += n;
    return r;
}
S operator - (const S& v, int n){
    S r = v;
    r.b -= n;
    return r;
}

S v = S() + 1 - 1;
```

Is it possible that `S() + 1 - 1` will be optimized to `S()` ?

How does a compiler even determines when this kind of things can be optimized?

Comment: Well, I am not a (language) lawyer, but I don't think this can ever be optimized in the way you suggest since the operators are not required to do what we would intuit about them.

Comment: I don't think so because `S() + 1 - 1` won't have the same value as `S()`.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it begins by inlining the `+` and `-` function calls, and seeing a few assignments only an increment and decrement to a variable occurs, that can be optimized out. A more complicated implementation of the operators won't be optimizable.

Comment: Here is [an example of optimization](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KhMzGn): Calls of the operators are skipped and the resulting values are directly assigned!

Comment: Such an optimization is allowed and possible for your example code (with all code in the same source file). Each version of each compiler may do optimizations differently. Try various compiler versions with various settings on https://godbolt.org/ .

Comment: "How does a compiler even determines when this kind of things can be optimized?" A compiler can inline a sequence of function calls and then prove that they have no net effect, and eliminate them. In your case they do have an effect though.

Comment: The compiler might optimize that to *as-if* `S() : a(1), b(9) {}` ... but that's not the same as `S()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, a compiler is not allowed to optimize

```
S() + 1 - 1
```

into

```
S()
```

because those two expressions are not equivalent for your class `S`.

Even though it might be non-idiomatic, it's completely valid for `S` to be written as you have done, in a way that `operator+` and `operator-` don't cancel each other out (in your case, by modifying different member variables in the 2 operators).

The compiler is required to evaluate `S() + 1` before using that result in the evaluation of `- 1`, and is only allowed to optimize that expression if it can prove that the resulting expression would be the same. In other words, the program must follow the *as-if* rule. Obviously, in this case the results would be different, and so the optimization is not allowed.

---

By the same token, if the compiler can see that an expression, and this can be any expression at all, is equivalent to some other expression, then it is allowed to optimize it as much as it wants. But again, the compiler must adhere to the *as-if* rule, i.e. the resulting program must behave exactly as if none of those optimizations were ever made at all.

---

Note that while your implementation of `S` is valid according to the language rules, it is quite strange, and will surprise users of the class. I suggest only doing that for types that are very clearly domain specific, and where users of the type naturally *expect* that `+` and `-` are not necessarily inverses of each other.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Ok, I see the demo. I'm not sure what your point is though.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. No worries :) You're definitely not the only one. I've asked the OP to be more explicit in the question.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid confusion, let's write it like this:

```
S a;
S b = a + 1 - 1;
```

To better see what happens in the last line you can rewrite the operator calls explicitly:

```
S b = a.operator+( 1 ).operator-( 1 );
```

Already here we see that the compiler cannot simply skip `+1 -1`. To do that it would have to first prove that applying `+1` and then `-1` to a `S` is the same as not applying any operation.

Usually that is the case, since typically `+` and `-` are inverses. However, your operators are not inverses of each other, as they increment/decrement different members.

> Is it possible that S() + 1 - 1 will be optimized to S() ?

No, because the result would not be the same.

> How does a compiler even determines when this kind of things can be optimized?

This is covered by the so-called *as-if* rule. If there is no observable difference, then compilers are allowed to transform the code to get an optimization. On the other hand, an optimization may never change observable behavior (there are a few exceptions, but they don't apply here).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux right. Shortly noticed it after reading the other answer, that either one must be wrong ;)

Comment: sometimes I am a bit puzzled by a comment pointing to a problem in the post collecting votes after that problem is gone already... whatever...

Comment: @idclev463035818 I upvoted that comment :p possibly after you made the correction, because I didn't read the answer fully. You might want to give the last sentence in your second-last para more prominence, since that is the core of the OP's question.

Comment: @cigien ok, agree that it wasnt clear enough. Imho the important detail that my answer adds is `a.operator+( 1 ).operator-( 1 );`, i think this helps to understand that `+1-1` is not necessarily equivalent to `+0`. Otherwise I was considering to delete it, however, tried to improve also the rest a bit

Comment: Ah, that's much better, thanks :) And no need to delete it, it's a good answer, and I like the explicit rewrite of operator calls as well. There's a couple of minor typos, do you mind if I fix that?

Comment: @cigien of course not. I make more typos than anything else recently...

Comment: Ok, edited. I took the liberty of a few copy-edits as well, hope that's ok. BTW, what do you mean by the very last statement (the *exceptions* bit)? Are you referring to copy-elision for example?

Comment: @cigien yes copy-elision, admittetly I am most familiar with c++11, not even sure if in newer standards it can even be called an "exception"

Comment: No, they're not really exceptions. From C++17 mandatory copy elision says "copy/moves in some cases are required to be elided, even if the cop/move constructors have observable side effects", but it still doesn't change the *as-if* requirements, since the *required* behavior is still mandated. It's fine to leave that wording in the answer though, I think.

Comment: @cigien: In addition to (N)RVO exception, there is also [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation) in C++14.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, that's cool, I didn't know `new` was allowed to elide stuff. Thanks for the pointer :)